# how to get specific field in an included object

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm trying to get a specific field in a api call from an included object.

I get an empty array.

filter =

> {"where":{"type":"person"}, "include":["objectA"], "fields":"objectA.name"}

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If for example you have the following data model:

```
Model: Customer.
Fields: id, name.

Model: Order.
Fields: id, date, description, customerId.

Order.belongsTo(Customer, {foreignKey: ‘customerId’});
```

You can get only the Customer name by writing this filter:

```
var filter = {
  "where": {
    "id": 1
  },
  "include": [
    {
      "relation": "customer",
      "scope": {
        "fields": [
          "name"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}

Order.find(filter, function(err, order) {
    ...
})
```

and in your case i'm guessing the filter suppose to be something like this:

```
{
  "where": {
    "type": "person"
  },
  "include": {
    "relation": "objectA",
    "scope": {
        "fields": ["objectA.name"]
    }
  }
}
```